# Checking for scale did not work

Tags: python

I'm trying to check the scale of an object and if it's not 1 1 1 then print its name

```
import bpy
#from mathutils import Vector

selected_all_meshes = [obj for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects if obj.type == "MESH"]    

#scale = Vector((1.0, 1.0, 1.0))
for obj in selected_all_meshes:
#    if obj.location[0] or obj.location[1] or obj.location[2] !=0:
#        print("Center not 0 0 0 :", obj.name)
#    if obj.rotation_euler[0] or obj.rotation_euler[1] or obj.rotation_euler[2] !=0:
#        print("Rotation not 0 0 0 :", obj.name)
    if obj.scale[0] or obj.scale[1] or obj.scale[2] !=1:
#    if obj.scale !=scale:
        print("Scale not 1 1 1 :", obj.name)
```

it works for location and rotation_euler but not for scale until I use a Vector. How to make it work without using Vector?

Comment: `x or y or z != 1` means `(x) or (y) or (z != 1)` which means `(x != 0) or (y != 0) or (z != 1)`. Either use `x != 1 or y != 1 or z != 1`, use the vector, or use `obj.scale[:] != (1,1,1)`.

Comment: Thank you! Make it as answer, I mark it